# get data of document reference field of another document in angularfire while retriving all docs of a collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular8, angularfire

[image: Here is the document storing model. Screen shot of firestore]

**I want to show retrive all the machine-site-map with machineRef and siteRef**

```
getActiveMachineSiteMap() {
    return this.db.collection('machine-site-map',
      ref => ref.where('IsActive', '==', true))
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'Id' });
}
```

By this i am not getting machine and site

Comment: Hi.. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the examples of the documentation about [Querying and filtering data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#execute_a_query), the method db.collection only uses one parameter. So in this case your function should be like 
Here is the document storing model. Screen shot of firestore
I want to show retrive all the machine-site-map with machineRef and siteRef

```
getActiveMachineSiteMap() {
    return this.db.collection('machine-site-map').where('IsActive', '==', true)
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'Id' });
}
```

There's also some documentation about [Collections in AngularFirestore](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) in github you can check, it might help you to solve some doubts.